# How to interpret the Microsoft Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

I've created many types of neural networks with Microsoft's data tools, but I still struggle with the interpretation.

My Neural Network output gives so weird numbers. For the output attribute "Total Spent" it contains ranges that have negative numbers (ex. -384 - -58) even though the data set I use contains no negative numbers.  What do these ranges actually mean and how am I supposed to interpret them correctly.

I have using a data set that on customer purchases and I group by CustomerID.  On the data set some customers purchase thousands of dollars with of goods and others spend fifty dollars.

Thank you in advance for the help.